# toggle the mousemove mousestop event

Tags: javascript, jquery

My question is simple. When my mouse moves, I would like to execute a function which would print `"you are moving"` in a `div` tag. When my mouse is not moving, I would like the text function to go away. 
Below is a pseudo code that i can think of. So for example, the text function will be called every 50/1000 of a second and check if the mouse is moving. if it is moving, the text will show. if the mouse is not moving, the text will not show. How can i achieve this since there is no mousestop event?

```
$(function() {  setInterval(text, 50);
});
function text() {
    /*Do something to check if mouse is moving*/
    /*if mouse is moving*/
    if{
        $("#shu").text("You are moving");
    } else {
        $("#shu").remove();
    }
}
```

Comment: Better you attach listener for `mouseenter`, `mousemove` and/or `mouseleave` event..

Answer (score 1):

Pure javascript solution:

```
var shu = document.getElementById("shu");
var timeout;

document.addEventListener("mousemove", function() {
  shu.innerHTML = "You are moving";
  if (timeout) clearTimeout(timeout);
  timeout = setTimeout(mouseStop, 150);
});

function mouseStop() {
  shu.innerHTML = "";
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/19c64Lh9/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(window).mousemove(
  function() {
    $("#shu").text("You are moving");
  }, function() {
   $("#shu").remove();
  }
);
```

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this". We make an effort here to be a resource for knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `.mousemove` function along with set interval to check the mouse movement.

Here is an example code.

```js
var lastTimeMouseMoved = "";
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    
   $(document).mousemove(function(e){
     $(".text").show();
   
       lastTimeMouseMoved = new Date().getTime();
       var t=setTimeout(function(){
           var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
           if(currentTime - lastTimeMouseMoved > 1000){
$('.text').fadeOut('fast');
             
           }
       },1000)
   }); 
});
```

```css
body{
    background-color:#333;
}
.text{
    display:none;
  color:white;
  font-size:25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="text">Your are moving!!</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function mouseStop(callback) {
  $(window).mousemove((function() {
    var t;
    return function() {
      if(typeof t !='undefined')
         clearTimeout(t); //we should check that `t` is not null
      t = setTimeout(function() {
        callback();
      }, 200)//change to 200 so it will not trigger on mouse move 
    }
  })())
}
mouseStop(function() {
  console.log("stop!!!")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

With jquery

```
var lastMove = new Date().getTime() ,currentTime;
$(window).mousemove(function(){
  lastMove = new Date().getTime();
});
  setInterval(function(){
currentTime = new Date().getTime();
if(currentTime - lastMove > 400)
    $("#shu").empty();
else 
    $("#shu").text("moving");
  },20);
```